# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I get this error or my jsp page every day:

```
java.net.SocketException
```

MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2637)
        ....
```

After restarting the tomcat service it works fine. (I use hibernate to connect to the mysql database)

Comment: @Carl I guess "Why does this exception occur?"

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your `<session-factory>`?

Answer (score 17):

> I get this error or my JSP page every day (...)

I'm going to speculate a bit but if this happens every morning (i.e. after a night of inactivity), then it might be related to the fact that MySQL closes idle connections after 8 hours by default (the [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)).

If this is the case, either:

- configure tomcat to test connections on borrow using a `validationQuery` in the datasource configuration:

  ```
  <parameter>
    <name>validationQuery</name>
    <value>select 1</value>
  </parameter>
  ```
- increase MySQL's `wait_timeout` via `my.cnf/my.ini`, or by connecting with a command-line SQL client and entering `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=86400`, or some other suitable number of seconds.

I'm not aware of all the consequences of the second option and don't really recommend it, at least not without getting more feedback from MySQL experts.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you (partially) loose the connection to your database. MySQL tries to send something but the connection is lost.

Another mysql/tomcat user who reported a similiar problem, was adviced to use a connection pool, like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0). The user replied that he wanted to use the Mysql/tomcat connection pooling first as described in [mysqls reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee.html).

[This is original post (german language)](http://serversupportforum.de/forum/sql/20906-mysql-tomcat-mit-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe.html).

Comment: He's using Hibernate which is by default often already configured to use a connection pool. It look like an improper Hibernate connection pool configuration.