# Default connection pool not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I saw some similar questions on stackoverflow, none of them helped. So here I go.

I am using the below libraries

- Spring Boot 1.2.0
- Spring Data JPA
- Hibernate 4.3.7
- Tomcat JDBC 8.015
- MySql Connector 5.1.34

On inspecting `poolProperties`in `tomcat.jdbc.pool.DatasourceProxy::createPool()` [method](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.html#createPool%28%29) I get the following

```
ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test; username=test; validationQuery=null; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false;
```

Yet, I get java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe every morning. Is anything wrong with my configuration ? I am not creating a DataSource. According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) everything should be autoconfigured.

Update: The exception I get is exactly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306244/java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe) question. In that question it is suggested to use a pooling mechanism. I am using a datasource pool still I am getting the problem

Comment: This is a known issue with MySQL as that will kill the connection after x time of idleness. Your connection pool thinks the connection is there but the lower level connection has been killed (most of the time by MySQL but could also be a firewall or something in your environment that kills idle connections). To fix specify that you want to auto reconnect and add a validation query for the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not address your specific problem (it's hard to be sure with the information you've provided) but I would recommend configuring a validation query that's appropriate for MySQL and enabling testOnBorrow, or similar.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. What additional details should I add to my question ?

Comment: More detail about the failure; the stack trace, for example. It would also help to know if the failure occurs while the app is being used or while it's idle. You said that you see the failure "every morning". Why is that? Perhaps it matches the application's usage?